# Test cases failing on Firefox but successfully execute on Chrome

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

For some reason that I just can't understand, my Test Cases failing on Firefox but successfully execute on Chrome.

For example, this simple Test Case will execute just fine on Chrome but will fail on Firefox:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  This is some test sample login test
Library  Selenium2Library
Resource  ../Resources/common_resources.robot
Resource  ../Resources/users.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Test Robot Framework Logging
    [Documentation]  Some info about the valid login test step
    [Tags]  Login
    Open Browser  ${LOGIN URL}  ${BROWSER}
    Input Text  Username  ${VALID USER}
    Input Password  Password  ${VALID PASSWORD}
    Click Button  Log On
    Page Should Contain  Welcome
    [Teardown]  Close Browser
```

However if I put a `Sleep 10` keyword between the button click and the assertion it works. This leads me to think that for some reason the gecko webdriver is involved on this.

I'm running the latest version of robotframework-selenium2library and the webdriver.

It is my understanding that including Sleeps on the code is not encouraged at all. How can I address this issue? Where should I be looking?

Many thanks for any advice you may have!

Comment: In your post there are two questions: the difference in behavior between FF and Chrome. The second one is about waiting strategies. It is recommended to stick to one question per post. In case you would like us to help you with your browser issue, then please provide us with more details to reproduce the issue. Exact browser versions and webdriver versions and if the site is accessible from the internet, the URL. Based on the provided basic example we'll not be able to help much.

Comment: What kind of a error message you get while running a tests with Firefox? How about Wait Until commands instead of a sleep?

Comment: My apologies if this came out as an ambiguous question, English is not my native language.

Versions: FF v52.0, Chrome v6.0.2924.87, geckodriver v0.15.0 and ChromeDriver v2.28 (32b). Updated both RF and selenium2library with pip.

The site is only accessible behind a VPN, I'm not allowed to share the url but it has the following format: https://mydomain/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f 

When I run the Test Suite with either browser I can successfully see the page and log in. With Chrome it waits until the page loads and check the assertion and with Firefox it doesn't (sans Sleep). Thanks!

Comment: @PONKA no error message, the run just fails. I checked the different `Wait Until` keywords but I don't think they are what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you should avoid a sleep. It's much better to wait for an explicit condition than to wait for a fixed period of time. If you get in the habit of calling `sleep` a lot, you'll end up causing your chrome tests to run much slower than necessary.

In my experience, tests run much slower on firefox than chrome, so you have to take care to wait for pages to load and for elements to become available. A simple solution might be to replace [page should contain](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Page%20Should%20Contain) with [Wait until page contains](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20Until%20Page%20Contains) with a suitable timeout.

You could also use a more advanced library that has some built-in support for waiting for pages to load, such as the [robotframework-pageobjectlibrary](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-pageobjectlibrary). This library makes it very easy to write your own keywords that have access to the full selenium API including its ability to [wait on various conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). The page object library also provides python context managers that wrap actions which cause new pages to load.

Comment: Hi! Wait until page contains with a timeout worked, thanks for that. If it's ok, may I ask whether this can be considered as a 'band-aid solution' instead of a proper approach? The reason I'm asking is because I want to form good habits rather being patching things around :P

Comment: @Xour: generally speaking, waiting for the page to contain something is the proper approach. Whether it's the proper approach in this specific case is a bit harder to say but it depends on what you're waiting for, whether it is part of the initial page load or an ajax call, whether you're trying to wait for something unique or not, and so on.

Comment: thanks, appreciate the answer! My apologies it took too long to get back at you. I will use now the `Wait Until Page Contains` keyword with a reasonable timeout (5 seconds should be more than enough).